# Plotting issue with PGFPlots `\addplot'

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

Can someone help with workaroung about such issue?

```
\addplot [only marks, mark=o] table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma] {data.dat};
```

works just fine, but

```
\addplot [only marks, mark=bullet] table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma]
```

doesn't show any mark.
I'll be appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Mark "bullet" is not defined in `pgfplots`. Available markers are listed in subsection 4.7.2 Markers, page 176. If you like to have new marker, than you need to defined it by `\pgfdeclareplotmark`.

Name *bullet* remind me to symbol `\bullet` used in math environments. Similar to it is marks `*`.